# What do colons mean in a subroutine definition?

Tags: perl

In [this source code](https://github.com/denny/ShinyCMS/blob/master/lib/ShinyCMS/Controller/FileManager.pm) i found this `sub` definition.

```
sub upload_file : Chained( 'base' ) : PathPart( 'upload-file' ) : Args( 0 ){
```

I don't understand what means those `:` colons and parameters. Can anybody point me to some docs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:Chained`, `:PathPArt` and `:Args` are [attributes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Subroutine-Attributes) provided by [Catalyst](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst%3A%3AManual%3A%3AIntro#Action_types).

Comment: Huh... accpeting (ofc) - but the "subroutine attributes" are totally new thing for me. Just found this nice answer about them: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/987293/632407)